# Easy way to add button to cell footer in static table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I want to add button with custom action to section footer, but i felt pain when do this. Because i need to set footer height to 0. Add another new section, and customize it. Is there a better solution how to add custom element to section footer, like in image.

Comment: `tableView(viewForFooterInSection:)` returns an `UIView` for your footer. Have you checked this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create footer view and the button.
2. Add the button to the footer.
3. Add the further to the tableFooter property.

`let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 20))
 let aboutButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))
 aboutButton.setTitle("About purchased items...", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 //Here you should set the proper autolayout constraint
 footerView.addSubview(aboutButton)
 tableView.tableFooterView = footerView`